# Failing to authorize connection to own GAE endpoints API with service account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, service-accounts, server-to-server

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to successfully authorize an API hit on the Google App Engine (GAE) project I'm running from a python script using OAuth2 and a service account.

I've created the service account, added the service account id to the allowed client ids in the api file, converted the private key from a .p12 to a .pem, and authorized the httplib2 call. I've tried passing the credentials using the .authorize() method and by loading the credentials as JSON and adding the access_token parameter to the headers manually --     `{"Authorization": "Bearer " + token_string}.`

Every call too the API yields "Invalid Token".

One strange thing I have been noticed in that when I first call SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, there is no access token in the credentials -- "access_token" is None. However, the access token does show up when I retrieve the credentials from the .dat file in storage.

Following are the GAE endpoints_api.py file, the python_test.py file, and the 401 response.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

First the app engine endpoints server file:

```
# endpoints_api.py running on GAE

import endpoints
import time
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID = 'random_account_id_string.apps.googleusercontent.com'
WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'random_web_client_id_string.apps.googleusercontent.com'
ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID

package = "MyPackage"

class Status(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)
    when = messages.IntegerField(2)

class StatusCollection(messages.Message):
    items = messages.MessageField(Status, 1, repeated=True)

STORED_STATUSES = StatusCollection(items=[
    Status(message='Go.', when=int(time.time())),
    Status(message='Balls.', when=int(time.time())),
    Status(message='Deep!', when=int(time.time())),
])

@endpoints.api(name='myserver', version='v1')
class MyServerApi(remote.Service):
    """MyServer API v1."""

    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, StatusCollection,
                  allowed_client_ids=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID,
                                      endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
                  audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE],
                  scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
                  path='status', http_method='GET',
                  name='statuses.listStatus')
    def statuses_list(self, unused_request):
        current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        if current_user is None:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('Invalid token.')
        else:
            return current_user.email(), STORED_STATUSES

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([MyServerApi])
```

next the local python script:

```
# python_test.py file running from local server

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import httplib2
import os.path
import json

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "service_account_string@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
ENDPOINT_URL = "http://my-project.appspot.com/_ah/api/myserver/v1/status"
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

f = file('%s/%s' % (SITE_ROOT, 'pk2.pem'), 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

http = httplib2.Http()
storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_EMAIL, key, scope=SCOPE)
    storage.put(credentials)
else:
    credentials.refresh(http)

http = credentials.authorize(http)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

(resp, content) = http.request(ENDPOINT_URL,
                           "GET",
                           headers=headers)

print(resp)
print(content)
```

Finally, the console output:

`{'status': '401', 'alternate-protocol': '443:quic,p=0.002', 'content-length': '238', 'x-    xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding':     'chunked', 'expires': 'Sun, 14 Sep 2014 23:51:36 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Sun, 14 Sep 2014 23:51:36 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest"'}`

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Invalid token.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid token."
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use the method above? There is a OAuth decorator that will handle all the work for you. It won't take much to re-write your code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine You give it your OAtuh details and it handles the tokens and the actual work.

Comment: I have zero clue what I am talking about, but it looks like that only works while you are in the app engine environment. You need to supply a private key if you are outside. I got a solution doing something very similar using the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials and build. I'll post it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. There are a couple things I did wrong above.

Firstly, I needed to reference the app engine project id in the allowed ids list.

```
API_ID = 'project-id-number.apps.googleusercontent.com'

@endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, StatusCollection,
              allowed_client_ids=[API_ID, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID,
                                  endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
              audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE],
              scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
              path='status', http_method='GET',
              name='statuses.listStatus')
```

I had incorrectly come to the assumption that the build() method would only work with official google APIS, but it turned out I was referencing my project incorrectly. With the project id in place, I could use build() instead of writing my own httplib2 call in the server side file (which didn't work).

Erasing the code beneath 'http = credentials.authorize(http)' I replaced it with the following:

```
myservice = build('my-service', 'v1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryServiceUrl)
data = myservice.my-path().endpoint-name()
results = data.execute()
```

This successfully authorizes my account and calls the endpoint. Woot! If anyone else has questions about this, or if my solution isn't clear, please feel free to comment. This was a painful process I don't wish upon anyone else.